# SSRS - permission issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have configured Reporting Services Manager in my machine. When I tried to access the ReportServer URL, I am receiving below error :

User '<>' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed

Anyone know how to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you try by running your browser using `Run as administrator`?

Comment: Is the report server itself a new installation?

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:
Source:https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/622737/user-does-not-have-required-permissions-verify-that-sufficient-permissions-have-been-granted-and-windows-user-account-control-uac-restrictions-have-been-addressed

For users to navigate to a particular folder, they must have Browser role on all folders starting at the root folder (the folder named "/" in the item path or "Home" in Report Manager). So you will need to grant those permissions explicitly. By default, permissions are inherited from the parent folder. If there are any breaks in the inheritance, you will need to set those permission exiplicitly.

I have closed this item because I do not see a bug here. If this is still a problem, simply respond in Connect and the issue will be automatically re-opened.